# php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript

hello i have a problem that's maybe difficult to descripe,

i have an application, that simulates a pizza store. i have a page "bestellungen" ("orders")
in which i have some javascript.(the head,javascript and body i declare in page.php, from which the other ("sub")pages "extends".

right now, everything works, but now, i want to add to the javascript some php code. (in the "main" page.

in the page "bestellungen" ("orders") i read from the database

```
$sql="Select * FROM pizzen_arten";
        $data=$this->_database->query($sql);    //alle daten in data gespeichert


        while($reihe = $data->fetch_array()){   

            $lfdnr=$reihe[2];                       
            $this->pizza_name[$lfdnr]   =$reihe[0];
            $this->pizza_preis[$lfdnr]  =$reihe[1];
            $this->pizza_id[$lfdnr] =$reihe[2];

        }
```

then in the same page i add all pizzas

```
foreach ($this->pizza_id as $tmp)   //alle pizzen durchgehen über id, (id in tmp speichern)
{
//echo " überall wo " ist ein \ davor
    echo "<img src=\"pizzen/pizza-".$this->pizza_name[$tmp].".png\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"Pizza ".$this->pizza_name[$tmp]."\" id=\"".$this->pizza_name[$tmp]."\" onclick=\"hinzu('".$this->pizza_name[$tmp]."')\" /> ".$this->pizza_name[$tmp]." ".$this->pizza_preis[$tmp]." &euro;"; 
    echo "<p/>";                                                                                                                                //vor variable " string beenden . für "+" dann var, dann string weiter
        //this das aktuelle obj, der schleife,  davon pizzaname (ist ein array! kein attribut), an der stelle tmp
}
```

the method "hinzu(id)" is declared in "page.php"

```
function hinzu (pizza)
{

    NeuerEintrag = new Option(pizza, pizza, false, false);
    document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").options[document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").length] = NeuerEintrag ;

ETO;



    foreach ($this->pizza_id as $tmp)
    {

        if ($this->pizza_name[tmp]==pizza)  //array durchgehen gucken, wann der übergabe parameter ==einem pizzanamen
            echo "gesamtbetrag=gesamtbetrag"+$this->pizza_preis[$tmp];
    }

    /*if (pizza=="Margherita")
    {
        gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag + 4;
    }

    if (pizza=="Salami")
    {
        gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag + 4.50;
    }

    if (pizza=="Hawaii")
    {
        gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag + 5.50;
    }*/

    echo <<< ETO

    document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML=gesamtbetrag ;

}
```

at first the method was without php-code, now by using php-code it doesn't work.

i suggest there might be a problem with "$this" or "pizza"  but i'm not quite sure wether i implemented the php code right.

thanks in advance

Comment: We can't really know, as we don't know what `$this` is referring to. You will need to start doing step-by-step debugging to find the root of the problem. For example, `echo "gesamtbetrag=gesamtbetrag"+$this->pizza_preis[$tmp];` will probably not do what you intend - look at the generated source code in your browser, you will find that a plus sign is (probably) missing. Etc. etc. Please try to walk through the code and describe more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: please clean your code up, and don't post unused code like in the JavaScript part the long code that is in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply mixup JavaScript and PHP code Like this. JavaScript Code is executed in the Users Browser and the PHP code is executed on your server. So you have to make clear which code is to be executed on you server. In PHP you do this with the PHP Tags `<?php` & `?>`:

```
function hinzu(pizza) {
  NeuerEintrag = new Option(pizza, pizza, false, false);
  document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").options[document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").length] = NeuerEintrag ;
  <?php foreach ($this->pizza_id as $tmp): ?>
    gesamtbetrag=gesamtbetrag + <?php= $this->pizza_preis[$tmp] ?>;
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML = gesamtbetrag;
}
```

or if I'm interpreting your heredoc strings correctly:

```
echo <<<ETO
  function hinzu(pizza) {
    NeuerEintrag = new Option(pizza, pizza, false, false);
    document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").options[document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").length] = NeuerEintrag ;
ETO;
foreach ($this->pizza_id as $tmp) {
  echo "gesamtbetrag=gesamtbetrag+" . $this=>pizza_preis[$tmp];
  // The important differnces:   ^  ^ 
}
echo <<<ETO
  document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML = gesamtbetrag;
}
ETO;
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing, but look at the context: this output is presumably already in a PHP block since the JavaScript bits are being output via `echo`. (Yuck... very yuck... but valid.)

Comment: It is deceiving, but if you look closely, you will notice that he is not mixing them up. He is using heredoc syntax `<<<ETO` to keep them separate. (As @Votey already says, yuck, but valid.)

Comment: @VoteyDisciple & @Pekka: You're absolutely right. I've ignored them, because they were incomplete. I tried my best to figure out what he wants to do. And my answer is what I've thought is what he wanted to do.

Comment: Sometimes generating JS with PHP can't be helped. What would you guys suggest as a better way of generating "dynamic" JavaScript?

I usually create a template file with the static JavaScript and a section like `/*{sources.identify}*/`, which is parsed by PHP and replaced with the output of a PHP function--in this case, `$SourcesController->identify()`. But ultimately, I still have embed some JavaScript code in my PHP.